# Can someone please delete the tag [softwaresugg]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/softwaresugg - this tag was only mentioned in one question, and I have deleted it from that question.

If relly needed, it could have a better name. And also some reference to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

However, I think that it was too specific to be of general use. Do you agree?

Answer (score 16):

[Unused tags are automatically purged by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71129/228441), so there's nothing further you need to do here. Thanks for deleting the tag :-)

Comment: Correct, see [main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it)

Comment: Does the daily "soft delete" or whatever prevent <300-rep users from reviving the tag?

Comment: No, but that's fairly unlikely in this case, so let's not worry about it. The linked answer gives more detail about what to do with "problem" tags.

Comment: @NickT I'm not aware of the soft-delete being a thing, I've commented on the linked question to ask for clarification.

Comment: @Lilienthal if you click the link in the post, on the first line it refers to the soft-delete thing.

Comment: @NickT ... I'm aware, which is why I asked the author of the linked post why he's referring to it as a soft-delete. It seems to be the only user referring to automated tag removal as distinct from a regular delete.